# Application Installation Failed (Android Studio) ; device not found

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

There's no problem with running a emulator on the Android studio.
when i run the app in mobile, "Application installation failed" dialog came.

Comment: Does this message still show up after clicking the OK button ?

Comment: Normally, relevant info should be available in logcat.

Comment: Is this your first time trying to install the app? maybe sdk version is incompatible.

Comment: That says nothing about "device not found"

Comment: are you testing on Xiomi device?

Comment: @Xema Yes, although I did click the Ok button, then I run the app in mobile, "Application installation failed" dialog came again.

Comment: @Egek92 No, I did installed several times. Before I meet the problem, I run the app well. but... after I remove the app in the mobile, I meet the "Application installation failed" dialog came. So.. To remove the app, I search for remaining data in sd card, but I didn't find.

Comment: clean your project and rebuild it again

Answer (score 13):

For me this problem was resolved by using a different usb cable to connect the phone to the computer.

Answer (score 2):

You can either continue by clicking ok button or uninstall the existing app and run it again.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions

- hit the `OK`-Button
- delete app from device manually
- re-plug device to usb
- restart device and/or Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

In my stuation, i had very low storage in my mobile phone after removing some useless files it worked. I've tried all suggestions in SO but none of them doesn't work except for deleting files.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the `adb server`.
That should fix it.

1. adb kill-server
2. adb start-server